# I am trying to use pointers to change the values in a struct via a function, but I get an error when inputting adress the in the function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a program where I first create a typedef struct in an inluded .h file like so

```
typedef struct {
 uint16_t x, y;
 } vector_t;
```

I then create a structure according to above definition in my main like so

```
vector_t vec = {5,10};
```

And then try to use it in the following function

```
void initVector(vector_t *v) {
 (*v).x = 10;
 (*v).y = 20;  
}
```

I input my function surrounded by to print statements like so.

```
printf("%d %d\n innit \n",vec.x,vec.y);

void initVector(&vec);

printf("%d %d\n \n",vec.x,vec.y);
```

However when I try to build the program I get the following error

```
expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token
```

When the function is commented out, the print statements gives the vector, so I do not think that is the problem, but I cannot see why it should not work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Post your ***complete*** code.  Errors from single lines of code are entirely meaningless as they have no context.

Comment: `void initVector(&vec);` is not a valid statement.  Replace with `initVector(&vec);`

Comment: Thanks Mike Nakis! now I feel realy stupid for having missed that in the past half hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want, is to call the function initVector, not to declare it, so you have to replace

```
void initVector(&vec);
```

with just

```
initVector(&vec);
```

BTW, in the function initVector, you can write:

```
void initVector(vector_t *v) 
{
    v->x = 10;
    v->y = 20;  
}
```